# Automatically update vault secrets into kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, hashicorp-vault, vault

All the secrets used by our application are stored in Vault. During deployment, we utilize an internal tool to retrieve secrets from Vault and load them onto the pods. Now, we have a secret which gets updated every month and it requires a restart or deployment. Is there a solution available that automates the process of updating the secret on the pod whenever it is modified on Vault? FYI - our secrets are loaded as files on the pods.

I checked online and I see two options:

1 - Vault agent used as side car container
2 - Vault operator (something new)

Comment: If the secret is dynamic (with the stated TTL of thirty days), then the Vault operator would work well. if it is static, then you would do better with the Vault agent.

Answer (score 1):

Sidecar would fit in nicely.

That Hashicorp [Vault Secrets Operator](https://www.hashicorp.com/blog/vault-secrets-operator-a-new-method-for-kubernetes-integration) could do as well, I guess -- I didn't know about it, TBH.

You could attach secrets as [CSI Volumes](https://developer.hashicorp.com/vault/tutorials/kubernetes/kubernetes-secret-store-driver)

Inject them using Hashicorp [Vault Agent](https://developer.hashicorp.com/vault/tutorials/kubernetes/kubernetes-sidecar)

And we could mention: the [External Secrets Operator](https://external-secrets.io/), which can integrate with other vaults (eg: aws, a remote kubernetes cluster API, ...)